# Multi-threaded ping script

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell, unix

I have this

```
#! /bin/bash

cd ~
hostname=`hostname`
cat /opt/ip.txt | while read line;
do
# do something with $line here
RES=`ping -c 2 -q $line |  grep "packet loss"`

echo "---" >> /opt/os-$hostname.txt
echo "---" 
echo "$line $RES" >> /opt/os-$hostname.txt
echo "$line $RES" 
done
```

How I can make the script multi-threaded? I would like to speed up the performance.

Comment: Take a look at [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) for parallel-processing. You may like to try something like: `parallel ping -c 2 :::: /opt/ip.txt | grep "packet loss"`. Goodluck!

Comment: Could you please show me some example how I have to edit this code?

Comment: Did you try GNU parallel and the one-liner above? If you're still struggling with the [man](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) page, I highly recommend going through this [tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) first. It's well worth the investment. HTH.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `<(...)` notation for starting a subprocess and then `cat` all the outputs together:

```
myping() {
  ping -c 2 -q "$1" | grep "packet loss"
}

cat <(myping hostname1) <(myping hostname2) ...
```

To use a loop for this, you will need to build the command first:

```
cat /opt/ip.txt | {
  command='cat'
  while read line
  do
    command="$command "'<'"(myping $line)"
  done
  eval "$command"
}
```

If you really want the delimiting `---` of your original, I propose to add an `echo "---"` in the `myping`.

If you want to append the output to a file as well, use `tee`:

```
  eval "$command" | tee -a /opt/os-$hostname.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

DELETED.
WAS UN USEFUL ? NO THREAD IN BASH.

Comment: Please add your answer in more detail